# Rails 4 Error: ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

Hey,
this is frustrating. I know what's wrong here, but I have no solution to fix it.

*First the error, prompting when clicking on 'Favorite' (/app/views/users/index.html.haml)*

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError in UsersController#userfavorite

Could not find the source association(s) "userfavorite" or :userfavorites in model FavoriteUser. Try 'has_many :userfavorites, :through => :favorite_users, :source => <name>'. Is it one of c_user_id or user_id?
```

*Request: Parameters:*

```
{"_method"=>"get",
 "authenticity_token"=>"VkZF4RtOBSXLFw8mygor24Ty/Efx5uSWxto4qRWf1szu3YwFe1/F5+7QtEXXZv9eaQEQvM5O8ELX95wmPLdZYQ==",
 "type"=>"favorite", # What i am doing
 "id"=>"1"} # My user id
```

**My goal is to allow Users (from the user model) to favorite other users (user model) through the favoriteuser model. The conflict here: I am not able to do the associations right cause I have only one model the data is coming from.**

Let me show you the code real quick! *(Conflicts user.rb)*

*app/models/favorite_user.rb*

```
class FavoriteUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :c_user_id
    belongs_to :user_id
end
```

*app/models/user.rb*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:

  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable


  has_many :tools

  # Favorite tools of user
  has_many :favorite_tools # just the 'relationships'
  has_many :favorites, through: :favorite_tools, source: :tool # the actual tools the user favorites

  # Favorite users of user
  has_many :favorite_users # just the 'relationships'
  has_many :userfavorites, through: :favorite_users, source: :user # conflicting! Can't link to userscontroller cause it belongs to the user model, the model we are at right now.
  has_many :userfavorited_by, through: :favourite_users, source: :user # conflicting! Can't link to userscontroller cause it belongs to the user model, the model we are at right now.



  mount_uploader :avatar_filename, AvatarUploader

end
```

*app/controllers/users_controller.rb*

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_user, only: [:show, :favorite]

    # Add and remove favorite recipes
    # for current_user
    def userfavorite
      type = params[:type]
      if type == "favorite"
        current_user.userfavorites << @user
        redirect_to :back

      elsif type == "unfavorite"
        current_user.userfavorites.delete(@user)
        redirect_to :back    
      else
        # Type missing, nothing happens
        redirect_to :back, notice: 'Nothing happened.'
      end
    end

    def index
        @users = User.all
    end

    def show
        @tools = Tool.where(user_id: @user).order("created_at DESC")
        @tool = Tool.find(1)
    end

    private

    def find_user
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

*app/views/users/index.html.haml*

```
- @users.each do |user|
    = image_tag gravatar_for user if user.use_gravatar == true
    = image_tag user.avatar_filename.url if user.use_gravatar == false
    %h2= link_to user.username, user
    %p= link_to "Favorite", favorite_user_path(user, type: "favorite"), method: :get
    %p= link_to "Unfavorite", favorite_user_path(user, type: "unfavorite"), method: :get
```

*app/config/routes.rb*

```
resources :users, only: [:index, :show, :userfavorite] do 
    get :userfavorite, on: :member
end
```

*Attributes of :favorite_users*

```
c_user_id:integer user_id:integer
```

*(=> c_user_id for currents user id - so the user who is adding favorite users)*

I hope the provided data is enough, if not please tell me. I'm grateful for all Your replies.

Comment: what are attributes for `:favorite_users` model?

Comment: @mrvncaragay c_user_id:integer user_id:integer (=> c_user_id for currents user id - so the user who is adding favorite users)

Comment: you didnt set up your relationships right e.g foreign_key. ill write up my suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

**user.rb**

`userfavorites` - will list all user you have favorited

```
has_many :favorite_relationships, class_name: "FavoriteUser", foreign_key: "c_user_id"
has_many :userfavorites, through: :favorite_relationships, source: :user
```

`userfavorited_by` - will list all user who favorited you

```
has_many :favorited_relationships, class_name: "FavoriteUser", foreign_key: "user_id"
has_many :userfavorited_by, through: :favorited_relationships, source: :c_user
```

**FavoriteUser**

**edited:**

```
class FavoriteUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :c_user, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :user, class_name: "User"
end
```

After you make changes, make sure to `test` first in your `console` that the relationships works. then make appropriate change in your view, controller etc...

Comment: Appreciate your answer, sounds good. But when I try that chrome outputs something which is pretty weird cause it lacks a 'do' in the FavoriteUser Class  c:/Users/Jonas/gitapps/ocubit/app/models/favorite_user.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' belongs_to :c_user_id, class_name "User" ^ c:/Users/Jonas/gitapps/ocubit/app/models/favorite_user.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' belongs_to :user_id, class_name "User" ^

Comment: Not a 'do' sry, but some other stuff, which is usually not in a class

Comment: yea that's strange. im looking at the code i posted and i don't see any syntax error. did you test it in your console?

Comment: That's what it does in the console (the same error): irb(main):002:0> User.find(1).userfavorites << @c_user_id.find(1)
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]

Comment: SyntaxError: c:/Users/Jonas/gitapps/ocubit/app/models/favorite_user.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
    {belongs_to :c_user_id, class_name "User"}
                 ^
c:/Users/Jonas/gitapps/ocubit/app/models/favorite_user.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
c:/Users/Jonas/gitapps/ocubit/app/models/favorite_user.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
        from

Comment: do you have this project uploaded in github?

Comment: not yet, would this help or do you need specific files or the gems I've installed?

Comment: its okay. ill just recreate your models on my local machine and test it and see if it works.

Comment: just updated my small changes. i tested it and it works as expected

Comment: you've forgot a comma in your edited answer. I'll try to continue fixing my problems when I get home later

Comment: ahh... I've fixed the Syntax error. You are also missing a colon after 'class_name' on both lines. Now I am getting a template is missing, I'll chack that out then

Comment: Yep made the changed.

Comment: I think I've got it working. Do you know how to target the favorited users of a user on _/app/views/users/index.html.haml_ ?

Comment: Yea just make another post regarding that question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39353525/rails-4-error-activerecordrecordnotfound-couldnt-find-id