# Rails 4 Error: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound Couldn't find id=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, controller

I'm fairly new to rails and into coding my first app. Just can't figure out how to target a user the current_user favorited (Three models: User, Tool, FavoriteUser).

Controller (Tools)

```
def index
  @favorites = current_user.favorites.order("created_at DESC")
  @userfavorites = current_user.userfavorites.order("created_at DESC")
  @tools = Tool.where(user_id: current_user).order("created_at DESC")
  @user = current_user.favorite_user # problematic!
  @cuser = current_user
end
```

Index View (Tools)

```
%h2 My Favorite Users
- @userfavorites.each do |user|
    = image_tag gravatar_for @user if @user.use_gravatar == true
    = image_tag @user.avatar_filename.url if @user.use_gravatar == false
    %h2= link_to @user.username, @user
    %p= link_to "Favorite", userfavorite_user_path(user, type: "favorite"), method: :get
    %p= link_to "Unfavorite", userfavorite_user_path(user, type: "unfavorite"), method: :get
```

If I run this in my browser it appears following error:

```
NoMethodError in ToolsController#index
undefined method `favorite_user' for #<User:0x39df638>
```

**FavoriteUser Database:**

```
user_id:integer #favorited
c_user_id:integer #active user
```

I simply can't figure it out.
Thanks in advance for your help!

**RELATIONSHIPS:**

*user.rb*

```
has_many :favorite_users # just the 'relationships'
  # Favorite users of user
  has_many :favorite_relationships, class_name: "FavoriteUser", foreign_key: "c_user_id"
  has_many :userfavorites, through: :favorite_relationships, source: :user

  # Favorited by a user
  has_many :favorited_relationships, class_name: "FavoriteUser", foreign_key: "user_id"
  has_many :userfavorited_by, through: :favorited_relationships, source: :c_user
```

*favorite_user.rb*

```
class FavoriteUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :c_user, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :user, class_name: "User"
end
```

**ROUTES**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  get 'welcome/index'
  resources :tools do
    member do 
      get "like", to: "tools#upvote"
      get "dislike", to: "tools#downvote"
    end
    get :favorite, on: :member
  end

  resources :users, only: [:index, :show] do 
    get :userfavorite, on: :member
  end

  authenticated :user do
    root 'tools#index', as: "authenticated_root"
  end

  root 'welcome#index'

  get '/search' => 'tools#search'

  get '/users' => 'users#index'
end
```

Comment: I have to say that it is very confusing having two variables with the same name `user` and `@user`. I would try to avoid that, it will avoid many headaches.

Comment: By the way, I think you don't really want to write `@userfavorite_user_path` but `userfavorite_user_path`

Comment: You're right! I just focused on @User to just get it appear - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the solution!

```
@userfavorites = current_user.userfavorites
```

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
@user = current_user.favorite_user
```

to:

```
@favorite_users = current_user.favorite_users
```

`user` has_many `favorite_users`

don't forget to rename the instance variable wherever `@user` was being called.

Comment: That works (at least in the controller // don't gives an error there). But I can't select attributes like username for example with this solution

Comment: It's a collection, you'll have to loop thought it

Comment: That's what I am doing, but I also want to access certain attributes of an user item in that loop (username)

Comment: In _app/views/tools/index.html_ I would like to output the username of the User: neither `@favorite_users.username` nor `@favorite_users.user.username` works ...